# How to use match.call() inside an RC class?

Tags: r, oop, lm

I've written my own little linear regression class, similar to lm, and would like to get it to print the "function call". I looked at the lm code and found match.call(), but I believe this only works because lm is defined through a function. I'm using an RC class, which gets initialized through the initialize function. I want to create my function using `linreg_mod <- linreg(formula=Petal.Length ~ Species, data=iris)` and have defined `.self$call <<- match.call(expand.dots=TRUE)` inside the initialize function. I know TRUE is the default for expand.dots, but either way it doesn't seem to do it. When I then call `linreg_mod$call` I get `.Object$initialize(formula = ..1, data = ..2)`. Does anyone know why it's giving me the ..1, ..2, rather than my input? Thanks!

Comment: FYI, the RC object system of R is essentially obsolete, and has be supplanted by the R6 system. For all intents and purposes R6 is a modern, superior version of RC.

Comment: @KonradRudolph in my answer, `args$data` has type `name`. I think the proper thing to do is use `eval()` to simply evaluate a `name`, rather than `get()`, which (I think) coerces the `name` to a `character` and then looks on the search path. But owing to a general hesitancy about using `eval()` I opted for `get()`, though I can't think of a an actual reason not to use `eval()` in this case. Do you have a view?

Comment: @SamR I would use standard evaluation to get at `data`, i.e. `list(...)$data` (it’s actually a bit weird that there is no more direct way to get at a specific `...` argument; this feels like an oversight: arguably `...elt('data')` should work). But between `eval()` and `get()`, I would *always* use `get()`, since it’s the less powerful operation (and thus more descriptive and less error-prone). In fact, the semantics of `get()` very closely emulate how R resolves names. (cont’d…)

Comment: @SamR … that said, `get()` *does not work here!* Because `args$data` isn’t a name. It’s an arbitrary expression (which *could* be a name, but doesn’t have to be). So in this context you *must* use `eval()` — but be sure to evaluate in the correct scope! Plain `eval()` would evaluate the argument in the scope of the function, and that’s incorrect. You need to use `eval.parent()` (or `eval(envir = parent.frame())`).

Comment: @KonradRudolph thanks this is helpful. I agree `list(...)$data` is a bit awkward but perhaps preferring standard evaluation is better - not least because you avoid the question we are now discussing. What do you mean when you say that `get()` does not work here? Using `get(args$data)` seems to produce the same output as `list(...)$data` (when provided as the `data` argument). Do you mean if something other than `iris` was provided as an input? Good point about `eval.parent()`.

Comment: @SamR Try `linreg(Petal.Length ~ Species, data = head(iris))`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I see now! That function call is completely routine - it never it occurred to me that it would cause problems. Illuminating. I've updated the answer now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `match.call()` in the usual way with a reference class. Here's a minimal example:

```r
lm_wrapper <- setRefClass("lm_wrapper", methods = list(
    match_call_demo = function(...) {
        # This method is just to demonstrate the output
        # of match.call() and not required in your class
        as.list(match.call())
    },
    linreg = function(...) {
        # The actual regression method
        args  <- as.list(match.call())
        lm(formula = args$formula, data = eval.parent(args$data))
    }
))
```

You can then call this with your arguments. First let's call the demo to show the output of `match.call()`. Note I have used `as.list()` here as it will be easier to parse the individual arguments. As the [R Language Definition](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.pdf) states:

> The components of a call object are accessed using a list-like syntax, and may in fact be converted to and from lists using `as.list` and `as.call`

```r
lm_model$match_call_demo(formula = Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
# [[1]]
# lm_model$linreg

# $formula
# Petal.Length ~ Species

# $data
# iris
```

Note that with this method it is necessary to [`eval()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/eval) the `args$data` argument in the parent frame, which in this case is the global environment. I initially used `get()` to do this. However, that works if the argument is a `name`, e.g. `iris`, but not if the argument is a call which we want to evaluate, e.g. `head(iris)`. Thanks to Konrad Rudolph for the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77213674/how-to-use-match-call-inside-an-rc-class?noredirect=1#comment136123101_77213674) explaining this.

To run the model we can simply provide the relevant objects of the list to the arguments.

```r
lm_model$linreg(formula = Petal.Length ~ Species, data = iris)
# Call:
# lm(formula = args$formula, data = eval.parent(args$data))

# Coefficients:
#       (Intercept)  Speciesversicolor   Speciesvirginica  
#             1.462              2.798              4.090
```

Note that alternately, and perhaps preferably, you can also take Konrad Rudolph's suggestion of using standard evaluation.

```r
lm_wrapper <- setRefClass("lm_wrapper", methods = list(
    linreg = function(...) {
        lm(formula = list(...)$formula, data = list(...)$data)
    }
))
```

I cannot find a huge amount of documentation about RC. The [Reference classes](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/R5.html) chapter of Advanced R by Hadley Wickham contains a little more info, although it appears to be in draft form. Wickham [advises](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/r6.html#why-r6) that R6 is preferable over RC for various reasons, one of which is that R6 has comprehensive documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! And indeed the documentation for RC is very minimal... I will look into R6 classes as well, thanks!